# Recommendation for Comments in new Django

Tags: django, comments

So, I noticed when I recently checked out the newest dev version of Django that support for the built-in comments system django has used is being dropped. The reason being that rarely is the built-in framework sufficient or efficient for a developer's needs.

I am aware of the suggestion to use a service like Disqus, and also aware that Django will retain the package for legacy purposes, but neither of these are optimal for many scenarios.

Disqus can't tie into a site's own user authentication without fancy javascripting, and even then it requires the users sign in using another service. This can be mitigated by a (rather expensive) Disqus subscription, of course, but again, not optimal in many cases.

Using a deprecated portion of a framework tends to be poor practice when building new apps, so that option is out for those of us who are picky about good practice.

In light of this, I was wondering, what are some suggestions from the community for how to build one's own comments system?  What would be the most pythonic/django-ic methods for a comments implementation which supports things like nesting, anonymous/authenticated commenting options, and perhaps even a dash of ajax support built-in? What about the ability to use one commenting solution for multiple models?

I hope this question is appropriate, as it is a bit abstract, but with deprecation looming, I think stack q/a could use somewhere for users to start! Thankyou for your time!

Comment: I notice that Disqus has a guide on how to use their authentication on your site for free: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/236206-integrating-single-sign-on . When you say using Disqus for authentication requires fancy javascript, is this the process you are talking about?

Answer (score 4):

Just because the built-in comments system won't be part of core Django anymore, that doesn't mean you cannot continue using it. It will be just an additional external dependency in the setup of your site.

As the documentation mentions it, the comments framework is available in an external repository:

https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments

You can use it, fork it, improve it. It just won't be part of core Django anymore. Just like South is not part of Django either, despite being pretty much essential...

Comment: I suppose this is true, but I really feel like this is an opportunity to move away from the limited django comment system.

Comment: @Dreadicon, you're absolutely right. I just realized now that your question is more about moving away from Django comments rather than sticking to it. Unfortunately I don't know what else is out there, your best bet is to ask around in the Django community directly, on irc, see https://www.djangoproject.com/community/. At Stack Overflow it's not recommended to ask questions like "what is a good framework for this and that", such questions quickly get closed.